# Casting user defined types in trigger - ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I've got this inheritance type structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cuenta_udt AS OBJECT (
    IBAN               VARCHAR(28),
    Saldo              FLOAT,
    Numero_de_cuenta   NUMBER,
    Fecha_creacion     DATE,
    Clientes           clientes_array) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE De_ahorro_udt UNDER Cuenta_udt (
    Interes         FLOAT,
    Ultimo_devengo  NUMBER ) FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Corriente_udt UNDER Cuenta_udt (
    Oficina_bancaria_Codigo     NUMBER,
    Oficina_bancaria_Direccion  VARCHAR(100),
    Oficina_bancaria            REF Oficina_bancaria_udt ) FINAL;
/
```

which becomes this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Cuenta OF Cuenta_udt (
    IBAN                        PRIMARY KEY,
    Saldo                       NOT NULL,
    Numero_de_cuenta            NOT NULL,
    Fecha_creacion              NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Now, I'd like to define a trigger which does some actions or some others depending on the specific data type (De_ahorro or Corriente) it is. I've tried this but doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizarSaldo
BEFORE INSERT ON Cuenta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.Interes IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Soy de ahorro');
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Soy corriente');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Error is:

PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INTERES'

How can I achive that?

I've already tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizarSaldo
BEFORE INSERT ON Cuenta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW IS OF (De_ahorro_udt) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Soy de ahorro');
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Soy corriente');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

But I'm getting this error: "`PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'`"

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?  I see that there is no space between `END` and `IF` in the trigger which would be a syntax error.  I don't know if that's the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @JustinCave question edited

Comment: Just try `:NEW.object_value IS OF (De_ahorro_udt)`

Answer (score 1):

Started as comment, but due to formatting issues moved to answer.

`Interes` is available only in `De_ahorro_udt`, not on `Cuenta_udt`. 
So when you have a reference to `Cuenta_udt` object you have no access to that attribute - and that is the root cause of the error.

You could try to cast `(:new as De_ahorro_udt).Interes` and see what happen or use `IS OF`.

[Additional materials](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/functions-and-operators-useful-with-objects.html#GUID-6CD85D07-1E06-4E42-A582-68F478040A39)

Comment: I tried both of them but none worked. I've edited the question including what I've tried